# Individually colored data ranges in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a columnrange series in my highchart, and I want to be able to set a specific color for each range in a series. As long as I just used one color, this worked fine:

```
data: [[1, 5, 10], [2, 10, 20]]
```

Here the first value in each list is the X and the next two is the start and the end of the Y range. In order to have a separate color for each range I figured I needed to use the "object notation" instead of the array notation, so I tried this:

```
data: [{ 
    x: 1,
    y: [5,10],
    fillColor: "red"
},{
    x: 2,
    y: [10,20],
    fillColor: "blue"
}]
```

This did however not work (got invalid values). I cannot see that this case is covered by the API doc: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

Does anyone know how I can have ranges (two Y values) with the object notation, or if there is another way I can color the ranges differently? PS: My Y values are actually date ranges, but I just simplified it for the example above.

Edit: Here is a jsfiddle showing what I try to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2JMF/1/ . If you change the type to "column", and change the y-values to just single integers, you see that it works fine. But with columnrange I cannot get it working.

Comment: Could you make a http://JSFiddle.net with your code?

Comment: Sure! Updated the question with a jsfiddle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proper options are `low` and `high`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Q2JMF/2/

```
data: [{ 
  x: 1,
  low: 7,
  high: 8,
  color: "red"
}, {
  x: 2,
  low: 6,
  high: 7,
  color: "blue"
}]
```

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed true. I think they should have had low/high as separate properties in the API documentation though. I see that it was mentioned in one of the examples as "Range series values are given by low and high.", but they are not listed in the tree structure on the left. That's why it did not occur to me that low and high were actually valid properties on the data object.

Comment: Yes, that was the page I was referring to to. But I think that it should have been listed in the tree structure in the left panel, as that is where you usually look to get an overview over the allowed object properties. It is only mentioned "in-line" once. But thanks again for pointing this out for me! :)